# Latex \kbordermatrix with row labels on the right side

Tags: math-mode, labels, bordermatrix

I'm needing to create a matrix enclosed with brackets `[]`,  not parentheses `()`,  with row labels on right side. Is this possible using `\kbordermatrix`?

For instance, in the following:

```
\kbordermatrix{\mbox{}& C_1 & C_2& C_3\\
R_1&1&2&7\\
R_2&2&1&8
}
```

I would like the labels `R_1` and `R_2` to be on the right side of the matrix not the left.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\newcommand{\mLabel}[1]{\mbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{blockarray}{c@{}ccc@{\hspace{4pt}}cl}
    & \mLabel{C_1} & \mLabel{C_2} & \mLabel{C_3} & & \\
    \begin{block}{[c@{\hspace{5pt}}ccc@{\hspace{5pt}}c]l}
      & 1 & 2 & 7 & & \mLabel{R_1} \\
      & 2 & 1 & 8 & & \mLabel{R_2} \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need it only for the 2x3 matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\let\SC\scriptstyle
\def\Biggg#1{\makebox(0,0){\put(0,-20){\bigg#1}}}
\begin{document}
$ \begin{array}{r@{\kern5pt}ccc@{}l>{\SC}l} 
        & \SC C_1 &\SC C_2 &\SC C_3\\
\Biggg[ & 1       & 2      & 7      & \Biggg] & R_1 \\
        & 2       & 1      & 8      &         & R_2
\end{array} $

\end{document}
```

[image]